# Isblank formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a case in excel where I need multiple characters in one cell in new line using & and char(10) function. Once the data is inside a cell I need to check if we have data then it should return the same data obtained via previous function and if there is no data it should say "Blank". Output after & and char function should be as highlighted in peach. Eg Below:

so I have data in F3,F4 and F5 now using formula I get it in G6. But, it could be that next month the value in F3, F4 and F5 are null and then the formula in G6 will return null/blank. I am trying a formula as in I6 but it is not returning "No Data" in case there is no data, it is returning blank and working fine in case we have data.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If there are no values in `F3:F5` then result of your formula is equivalent to `=ISBLANK(char(10)&char(10))` and it is `FALSE`. Even `=ISBLANK("")` is `FALSE`. Use something like this:

```
=IF(AND(F3:F5=""),"No data",F3&CHAR(10)&F4&CHAR(10)&F5)
```

[image]

or

```
=IF(AND(F3:F5=""),"No data",TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,F3:F5))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much this helps a lot and works fine for my case.

Just a quick question what is AND exactly doing here, I mean it should read like IF this AND this then xx else YY. in the above formula it should if (F3:F5)="" AND what?

Comment: In this case AND(F3:F5="") works like AND(F3="",F4="",F5="") and returns TRUE when all 3 cells are empty. So if IF statement is TRUE it returns "No data" else it makes calculation.